# Durandaljs shell is not rendering corectly

Tags: durandal

I have following `shell.js`

```
define(function (require) {
    var router = require('durandal/plugins/router');

    return {
        router: router,
        activate: function () {
            return router.activate('movies/show');
        }
    };
});
```

and following `shell.html`

```
<div>
    <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <ul class="nav" data-bind="foreach: router.visibleRoutes">
                <li data-bind="css: { active: isActive }">
                    <a data-bind="attr: { href: hash }, html: name"></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container-fluid page-host">
        <!--ko compose: { 
            model: router.activeItem, //wiring the router 
            afterCompose: router.afterCompose, //wiring the router 
            transition:'entrance', //use the 'entrance' transition when switching views 
            cacheViews:true //telling composition to keep views in the dom, and reuse them (only a good idea with singleton view models) 
            }--><!--/ko-->
    </div>
</div>
```

But when I run my application, first div in the `shell.html` having `class="navbar navbar-fixed-top"` never renders. What am I missing?

Comment: Not seeing anything wrong with what you provided.  What about your router.map and/or .mapNav settings?  Did you change up the  UseConvention() on router or viewLocator?

Comment: @mikekidder I just posted answer myself. It was some strange behaviour on part of Resharper that caused this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be a silly mistake. I use ReSharper quite heavily. So I created a `shell.html` and then hit `F6` to move it to `view` folder. Resharper instead of moving, copied the file thus leaving the old file behind. All this while I was editing the wrong file. Now I have one `shell.html` and everything works just ok.

Comment: :) The convention is really important in that case. Because DurandalJs used a lot of ideas from Caliburn framework. The configuration over Convention is a heart of that framework.

Comment: Do you mean Convention over configuration?